# How to calculate the MSE of my estimator for coin toss with probability with $p$ of landing head?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, expectation

Suppose my estimator estimate the number of heads obtained by fliiping a coin with probability $p$ as $\frac{H}{N}$. Then I need to find the MSE of this estimator. My calculation is as follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
% \begin{split}
bias(\hat{\theta}_{MLE}) &= \mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}_{MLE}] - \theta \\
      &= \mathbb{E}[\frac{H}{N}] - p \\
      &= \frac{\mathbb{E}[H]}{N} - p \\
      &=\frac{Np}{N} - p \\
      &= p - p = 0 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
var(\hat{\theta}_{MLE}) &= \mathbb{E}[(\hat{\theta}_{MLE})^2] - (\mathbb{E}[\theta])^2 \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(\frac{H}{N})^2] - p^2 \\
&= \frac{\mathbb{E}[H^2]}{N^2} - p^2 \\
&= \frac{N^2p^2 - Np^2 + Np}{N^2} - p^2 \\  
&= p^2 + \frac{Np - Np^2}{N^2} - p^2 \\  
&= \frac{p-p^2}{N} \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
MSE(\hat{\theta}_{MLE}) &= var(\hat{\theta}_{MLE}) + (bias(\hat{\theta}_{MLE}))^2 \\
&= \frac{p-p^2}{N} + 0 \\
&= \frac{p-p^2}{N}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I am not sure if it is correct, inparticular, I am not sure if i can take $E[\frac{H}{N}] = \frac{E[H]}{N}$.

Hope that someone can verify my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine, as you take $N$ to be constant. Note that basically your estimator is the sample mean $\bar{X}_N$ where $X \sim Ber (1, p)$, hence
$$
Var(H/N) = Var(\bar{X}_N)=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i=1}^NVar(X_i)=\frac{Np(1-p)}{N^2}=\frac{p(1-p)}{N}.
$$